# Simple system of two nonhomogeneous ordinary differential equations solved by elimination. (Ex 3.1-2)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

**Update: I was able to solve it on my own after all.**

This problem is actually an example in my differential equations textbook which I cannot seem to duplicate. My textbook states to use the "elimination method" to crack this. The final answer uses $t$ as the independent variable which both $x$ and $y$ are dependent on. This is a linear nonhomogeneous equation however I only need assistance with deriving the characteristic equation of the homogeneous part of the general solution.

The textbook states that the general solution for both $x$ and $y$ are:

$$\begin{align*}
&x(t) = c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{2t}-3\cos t-\sin t &\\
&y(t) = c_1e^{-t}+4c_2e^{2t}-7\cos t+\sin t &
\end{align*}$$

The system consists of the following two linear ordinary differential equations:

$$\begin{align*}
&(1) \: x' = -2x + y&\\
&(2) \: y' = -4x + 3y + 10\cos t&
\end{align*}$$

The textbook states that the general solution in terms of $x$ should look like this (this is where I am having difficulty):

$$ x'' - x' -2x = 10\cos t $$

That was the part of the problem that I cannot seem to duplicate. Here is what I get when I attempted to work this example problem:

From $(1)$ above I solve for $y$ to get:

$$y = x' + 2x$$

Furthermore I differentiate for $y$ producing:

$$y' = x'' + 2x'$$

Now I am ready to insert $y$ and $y'$ (substitutions shown within parenthesis) into $(2)$ from above resulting in the following steps to get an equation in terms of $x$ and $t$:

$$
(x'' + 2x') = -4x + 3(x' + 2x) + 10\cos t \\
x'' + 2x' = -4x + 3x' + 6x + 10\cos t
$$
This yields the following:

$$
x'' - x' - 2x = 10\cos t 
$$

This time my solution worked. This happens often with me. I don't get the correct solution while writing down on paper but it comes to me when posting it on Mathematics StackExchange. No further help required. I apologize if I wasted your time.

Comment: If you think this problem will be generally useful to future visitors, you should [edit] the question so that it contains only the problem statement, and move the solution into an answer post so that its usefulness and accuracy can be reflected through community voting, independent of the merits of the question itself. See the Help Center article [*Can I answer my own question?*](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for more about self-answers. If you would rather not go to this effort, I recommend deleting the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is shown in the body of the post. The answer to this problem is:
$$\begin{align*}
&x(t) = c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{2t}-3\cos t-\sin t &\\
&y(t) = c_1e^{-t}+4c_2e^{2t}-7\cos t+\sin t &
\end{align*}$$